# Add character to subset of strings in dataset

Tags: string, r, conditional-statements, character, addition

Suppose I have a dataset:

```
test = data.frame(x=c(1:11), y=as.character(c(1:11)))
```

where the collumn 'y' is made up of characters/strings.
Now, I would like to change the strings containing two characters (i.e. test[10,2] & test[11,2]) so that those strings start with a character "0". The result of this would be "010" & "011", whereas the other strings (with only one character) remain the same.
To me, the logical solution would be:

```
test[nchar(test[,2])==2,2] = paste(c("0", test[nchar(test[,2])==2,2]), collapse="")
```

Indeed, only test[10,2] & test[11,2] are affected. The odd thing is though, that the result is test[10,2] = "01011", and test[11,2] = "01011". This means that all strings having two characters are pasted together with a preceding "0". This definitely is not what I would like to see.

What should I do to add only one character to a string in a dataset when certain conditions (of length) are met?
Your answer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
paste("0", test[nchar(test[,2])==2,2], sep="")
```

so for example

```
> test[nchar(test[,2])==2,2] = paste("0", test[nchar(test[,2])==2,2], sep="")
> test
    x   y
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
4   4   4
5   5   5
6   6   6
7   7   7
8   8   8
9   9   9
10 10 010
11 11 011
```

`collapse` and `sep` have different properties

```
> paste(1,c(2:3),collapse=',')
[1] "1 2,1 3"
> paste(1,c(2:3),sep=',')
[1] "1,2" "1,3"
```

Comment: Wow guys, great and swift respons! All your methods brought me the correct solution (as you already knew of course!). @James, Thank you as well, and thank you for showing me a completely different way of doing things using transform! I'm still very much learning R

Comment: @Liz Sander, Thank you as well of course for pointing to `paste0`!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it would be more readable using `ifelse`:

```
transform(test,y=ifelse(nchar(y)==2,paste0("0",y),y))
    x   y
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
4   4   4
5   5   5
6   6   6
7   7   7
8   8   8
9   9   9
10 10 010
11 11 011
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do the same thing as ttmaccer suggests, except that I would use paste0, which automatically concatenates them without any spaces. It's a bit more efficient than paste, so it can be worth doing if you have a large dataset. It means you don't have to remember the 'sep' argument either.

```
test[nchar(test[,2])==2,2] = paste0("0", test[nchar(test[,2])==2,2])
```